# Stored Procedure Not Accepting Integer Parameter

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, stored-procedures

I have been using a Stored Procedure created by our DB guy, who happens to be out of town for the next week. The SP used to work, but before he left, the DB guy edited the SP, causing my code to throw a server error: "Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition". He claimed before he left the SP should mainly be the same, so I'm at a loss for why it's no longer matching.

Here is the c# code:

```
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand objCmd = new 
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("dci.webDonorStatistics", objConn);
    objCmd.CommandTimeout = 950;
    objCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    objCmd.Parameters.Add(new 
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@FiscalYear", 2018));
    GridView1.DataSource = objCmd.ExecuteReader();
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

Here is the declaration of the SP:

```
   ALTER PROCEDURE [dci].[webDonorStatistics] @FiscalYear INT
   AS
   BEGIN
    --DECLARE @FiscalYear INT = 2018

   DECLARE
   @StartDate DATE = CONVERT(DATE, '01-OCT-' + CONVERT(CHAR(4), @FiscalYear - 1))
   , @EndDate DATE = DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())

   IF @EndDate >= CONVERT(DATE, '30-SEP-' + CONVERT(CHAR(4), @FiscalYear))
    SELECT @EndDate = CONVERT(DATE, '30-SEP-' + CONVERT(CHAR(4), @FiscalYear))
    ELSE
     SELECT @EndDate = DATEADD(DAY, -1, CONVERT(DATE, '01-' + DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE()) + '-' + CONVERT(CHAR(4), YEAR(GETDATE()))))  -- End of previous month

    IF DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate) < 0
    SELECT @EndDate = GETDATE()

    BEGIN TRY
     DROP TABLE #webDonorStatistics
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
    END CATCH
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you try to run the sproc from SQL Server Management studio?

Comment: I've only ever seen that error message when a table structure was changed but some query still referenced an old column name, or tried to `INSERT` without the correct number of columns specified. Are you sure this is where the exception is thrown?

Comment: The really odd part is that, as far as I can see, there's no table reference outside of the `try` block. Are you sure you're talking to the right server & database? I would roll the sproc back to the previous version (surely, happily saved in source control) to fix your error, and compare the two versions.

Comment: There must be more to this procedure than what's shown. You have an unmatched `BEGIN` at the top of the code, your local variables aren't being used for anything, and your calling code is clearly expecting a result set.

Comment: The error was also occurring on Management studio, so it seemed to be a bug in the stored procedure. It's been corrected by our DB guy now. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First step is to isolate your error. Is your error thrown from your application code or database code? 
If you follow [3Dave's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/135769/3dave) suggestion, what do you get? Assuming you are pointed to the correct database server. Try running:

```
EXEC [dci].[webDonorStatistics] 2018
```

If the above call does not return any error, I would check the application code.

Comment: Error was occurring in Management studio as well, so it was a bug in the stored procedure that our DB guy has now fixed. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your Error indicates that the data which you are trying to insert into the table is not valid, You would have to right-click on the stored procedure and click on execute stored procedure where you can  insert the parameter for the fiscal year, The execution should fail. Then create a copy of same stored procedure with a different name and change the data type for the fiscal year and see if that would fix the issue and give you the result when you execute the stored procedure. Also on the Stored Proc could which you have I dont see any insert commands if there are any try checking the data type of what you are trying to insert and the data type of what is present inside the table schema if that doesn't match then you can change accordingly .